# std::string vs std::wstring в русскоязычном приложении

Tags: c++, qt, кодировка

Поскольку в свое время плавно переехал с чистого C на С++/Qt, то все проблемы unicode остались за кадром, скрытые внутри `QString`. Теперь при переходе на std возникает вопрос в чем хранить строковые переменные и какие потенциальные проблемы может это вызвать.

Поиск не дал однозначного ответа, т.к. советуют использовать `wstring`, если есть данные unicode. Но при этом я сейчас спокойно выкачиваю информацию из базы данных PostgreSql, где все в юникоде, в `std::string` и никаких проблем с кодировкой нет. Задайте пожалуйста правильное направление, чтобы потом не было мучительно больно :)

Comment: `std::string` с его однобайтовой кодировкой может хранить символы максимум двух языков (английского и локалеспецифичного), ну и *некоторые* символы. Плюс вам иногда придётся хранить идентификатор используемой кодовой страницы. `std::wstring` же при использовании в нём UTF-16 или UCS-2 позволяет использовать единый Юникод, поддерживающий все письменности мира и огромную кучу знаков сразу (одновременно). Хотя, в `std::string` можно использовать и UTF-8, но стандартной библиотекой такой сценарий не поддерживается.

Comment: http://utf8everywhere.org/

Comment: Сравнил производительность QString с std::string и std::wstring в операциях конкатенации и копирования.  QString и std::string практически одинаковы (это странно, т.к. std::string не поддерживает copy-on-write, в отличие от QString). А вот std::wstring проигрывает остальным больше чем в три раза. Видимо связываться с wstring в русскоязычном ПО смысла нет вообще.

Comment: @jfs: Ага, и отрезать первый символ становится сразу очень нетривиальной операцией.

Comment: @nrw: А у вас в программе миллионы строковых операций в секунду? Если нет, то какая разница?

Comment: @nrw: Unicode — это не кодировка. Кодировки — это, например, utf-8, utf-16, utf-32, ucs-2 и т. д.

Comment: @VladD utf-16 code unit не всегда целиковый символ представляет также как и utf-8 code unit. И даже Unicode codepoint не всегда полный символ. По ссылке есть описание что такое character в разных ситуациях.

Comment: @jfs: Да, я знаю. Но в большинстве практических приложений достаточно UCS-2. Кроме того, в отличие от Питона, в C/C++ стандартная библиотека никак не поддерживает кодировки с переменным размером символов. Поэтому использование кодировки переменного размера на C/C++, хотя и даёт универсальное решение, по факту крайне непрактично.

Comment: @VladD: "А у вас в программе миллионы строковых операций в секунду? Если нет, то какая разница?". У меня таблицы БД на 200000 строк, по 200 колонок - это реальность и зачастую их надо анализировать вручную, без sql запросов. Так что разница думаю будет.

Comment: @nrw: Ну, тогда попробуйте попрофилировать std::string с utf8-операциями, и std::wstring с ucs-2 на **тех операциях, которые нужны вашей программе** (это важно). Учтите, что в utf-8 операция «найти i-ый символ» требует пробега по всей строке.

Comment: @VladD "достаточно UCS-2" — вот благодаря таким людям у нас всё ещё полно сломанных приложений, хотя это rocket science чтобы не рубить символ. На дворе не 90-ые годы прошлого века, ожидать что курсор со смайликом будет работать — это не слишком много требовать.

Comment: @jfs: Ага, это благодаря мне, а не благодаря идиотам^W авторам стандартной библиотеки, у которых строка = массив символов, и операции с utf-XX нужно кодировать самим вручную. Лозунги «utf8 везде» говорить всякий горазд. Но кто так говорит, пусть сначала заглянет в лицо реальности. А в реальности вы предлагаете придумать и закодировать самостоятельно utf8 API.

Comment: @jfs: И да, хороший API — это rocket science. Например, нужно продумать, как итерировать по строке. Что должно быть текущим элементом итерации? Новая строка? А где её аллоцировать, и не дорого ли это? Указатель на символ? А как передавать длину? Отказаться от API с итераторами, и сделать, чтобы строки вообще не ложились на стандартные средства языка? Я, например, решить не могу сходу. Вы можете?

Comment: @VladD вы начали с того, что в utf-8 отрезать первый символ не просто. Я ответил, что и в utf-16 это также не просто. Вы ответили что "достаточно UCS-2" и позже как всё тяжело "в рамках реальности". Я повторяю, что мы можем лучше.  Это не теория. К примеру, я смотрю что Chromium умеет даже с такими символами работать как комбинация U+1f1f7 U+1f1fa  Внутреннее представление строк  не так важно, если вы понимаете что делаете и не пытаетесь с помощью наивной индексации символы резать.

Comment: @jfs: Да, в utf-16, говоря строго, это тоже сложно (хотя и попроще, чем в utf-8). Но я говорил о том, что проще всего в UCS-2, и да, эмодзи при этом поддерживаться не будут. А то, что гугл написал свою библиотеку работы с utf8 — ну да, молодцы. Они и поисковик тоже написали. И для них, если что, не проблема работать с несовершенным API. А советовать другим использовать «строку», с которой не работает range-based for, я лично не буду.